# Python regex for below regex

Tags: c#, python, regex

I want to use following regex in python which is currently I am using in C#.

```
                (?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&\'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$
```

what changes to make?
I am getting bad character warning

I am getting bad character message in [pythex](https://pythex.org)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew bad character

Comment: Can you show the snippet of your code how you are using that regex?

Comment: I doubt your regex worked in C# as it is. Your regex start is not correct `@"^(?("")` You have `(` followed by `?` and at least `?` should be escaped.

Comment: The expression seems rather complicated. Please provide example strings and what you want to achieve with em (extract, validate, replace, etc.) so that we can further help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your **implicit lookahead conditionals** `?("")` and `?(\[)`
They are interpreted as **lookaround conditionals**, since they are not a named capturing group. Erasing them would give you an equivalent regular expression.

```
 (("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&\'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))((\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$
```

Leaving them out, just means that the full regular expression is evaluated. In C# the condition would be evaluated and **only** if true the full regular expression after the conditional is evaluated. If you leave it out in c# you would just lose performance.

For further reading I recommend:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#alternation_constructs
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html